# Cannot open new SSH connections after a certain amount of time

Tags: networking, ping, alpine-linux, openssh

I have a web server running Alpine linux and OpenSSH. When I power on the server, for about an hour or two I am able to open SSH connections and send commands fine. However, after that, even though the server is up, it does not respond to pings and I cannot SSH in to it. The server is still running, and I can still access the website being served from it. Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Ok, I will move my question there.